# What is the equivalent of 'sudo yum install -y awslogs' for apt-get?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, centralized-logging

According to [aws documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_cloudwatch_logs.html#installing_cwl_agent), this is the command to install the aws-log agent:

```
sudo yum install -y awslogs
```

However since I am using ubuntu, I have to use `apt-get`. But the `aws-log` package is not available.

Is there an equivalent of the `aws-log` for ubuntu? If not, how can I install it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html for installation instruction for ubuntu/debian:

Get installer with

`curl https://s3.amazonaws.com//aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -O`

and run the installer

`sudo python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py --region us-east-1`

After you have installed the agent, proceed to the next section to configure the agent.

Answer (score 3):

The CloudWatch Logs agent `awslogs` RPM package is only available on Amazon Linux. If you have Ubuntu Server, CentOS, or Red Hat, you'll need to  manually install it.

You need to have Python installed and `apt-get update` is recommended before installing the CloudWatch Logs agent. You have two options.

1. Run directly from the internet:

   ```
   curl https://s3.amazonaws.com//aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -O
   sudo python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py --region us-east-1
   ```
2. Install standalone:

   ```
   curl https://s3.amazonaws.com//aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -O
   curl https://s3.amazonaws.com//aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/AgentDependencies.tar.gz -O
   tar xvf AgentDependencies.tar.gz -C /tmp/
   sudo python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py --region us-east-1 --dependency-path /tmp/AgentDependencies
   ```

With both options the `--region` can be `us-east-1`, `us-west-1`, `us-west-2`, `ap-south-1`, `ap-northeast-2`, `ap-southeast-1`, `ap-southeast-2`, `ap-northeast-1`, `eu-central-1`, `eu-west-1`, or `sa-east-1`. For details, see [Install and Configure the CloudWatch Logs Agent on a Running EC2 Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html).